# Missing base case for Python recursion

Tags: python, recursion

I recently found some code that did not seem to have base case defined for recursion, but it worked fine.

This is a solution for leetcode question 690. Employee Importance.

```
class Solution(object):
    def getImportance(self, employees, id):
        """
        :type employees: Employee
        :type id: int
        :rtype: int
        """

        employee_dict = {employee.id : employee for employee in employees}

        def helper(id):

            ans = employee_dict[id].importance

            for x in employee_dict[id].subordinates:

                ans += helper(x)

            return ans

        return helper(id)
```

All I know about recursion is that you must have a base case to return, otherwise it is going to run forever. But how come this one didn't come with the base case? Could some one explain it? Thanks!

Comment: The base-case is when the employee has no subordinates i.e. `employee_dict[id].subordinates` is empty

Comment: On a side-note: `id` is a very bad name for a variable. It's shadowing the builtin function `id()`

Comment: @rdas thanks for the response. Didn't know that you can define the base case implicitly